# Unable to compile php module apcu on M1 Mac

Tags: php, macos, clang++, apple-m1

I've been trying to complile php apcu on my m1 mac without success, everythime I compile it produces:

```
modules/apcu.so: Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64
```

I've tried with the following options (cleaning and building each time) with no luck:

```
./configure --with-php-config=/opt/homebrew/opt/valet-php@7.2/bin/php-config --target=aarch64-apple-darwin20 --host=aarch64-apple-darwin20 --build=aarch64-apple-darwin20
./configure --with-php-config=/opt/homebrew/opt/valet-php@7.2/bin/php-config --target=arm64-apple-macos11 
./configure --with-php-config=/opt/homebrew/opt/valet-php@7.2/bin/php-config --target=arm-apple-darwin
./configure --with-php-config=/opt/homebrew/opt/valet-php@7.2/bin/php-config --target=aarch64-apple-darwin20

file modules/apcu.so
modules/apcu.so: Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64
```

I did some googling and found different articles which all seemed to get `arm64-apple-darwin20.1.0` when checking there target for cc, but I get the following:

```
~/D/apcu ❯❯❯ clang++ --version                                                                                                               
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

~/D/apcu ❯❯❯ cc --version                                                                                                                     
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

~/D/apcu ❯❯❯ ./config.guess                                                                                                              
x86_64-apple-darwin20.3.0
```

I raised an issue to then github here - https://github.com/krakjoe/apcu/issues/419

Does anyone have any ideas? Not done much compling before so any help would be awesome! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It reads `x86_64` and not `ARM64` (or alike). Try to clean the project once and then configure and build it again for the correct architecture (as you might have previously cross-compiled that file for the wrong architecture).

Comment: Hi Martin, just to be safe I went a head and deleted the source project, recloned from git and ran with the `--target=arm-apple-darwin` flag and got the exact same out. Even though it says `checking target system type... arm-apple-darwin` it never seems to actually use it :(

Answer (score 0):

After some help from some very helpful people on twitter I found I was running the commands from a terminal which had launched bash into i386 mode and not arm64 like I thought.

I was using vscode built in terminal which showed i386 when running `arch`. When performing `arch` from iterm it showed arm64. After trying my commands from iterm everything worked as expected.